# A Software to Improve the students' ability of reading and pronunciation

Tags: language

I am looking for any platform application that Monitors and Improves the student ability to read and pronounce characters correctly: for example a text to be read by the student, the application gets the student pronunciation and compare it with the text itself, and put on green the correctly pronounced words.